# Remove 100,000+ nodes from a Boost graph

Tags: c++, boost

I have a graph ( adjacency_list (listS, vecS, bidirectionalS, VertexVal) ) in which I need to delete 100,000+ nodes. Each node also contains a structure of 2 64-bit integers and another 64-bit integer. The guid check that happens in the code below is checking 1st integer in the structure.

On my laptop ( i7 2.7GHz, 16GB RAM ) it takes about 88 seconds according to VTune.

Following is how I delete the nodes:

```
  vertex_iterator vi,vi_end;
  boost::tie(vi, vi_end) = boost::vertices(m_graph);
  while (vi!=vi_end) {
    if (m_graph[*vi].guid.part1 == 0) {
      boost::remove_vertex(*vi,m_graph);
      boost::tie(vi, vi_end) = boost::vertices(m_graph);
    } else 
      ++vi;
  }
```

Vtune shows that the boost::remove_vertex() call takes 88.145 seconds. Is there a more efficient way to delete these vertices?
[image: Vtune data for boost::remove_vertex_dispatch(). This is the breakdown of the 88 seconds]

Comment: and the graph type is... (you should specify the relevant information. (Bundled) properties, container selections, they'll have a huge impact)

Comment: adjacency_list with (listS, vecS, bidirectionalS, VertexVal.)

Comment: Each node also contains a Vertex Value which is a structure that has 3 64-bit integers.

Comment: The guid is a structure with 2 64-bit integers - 2/3 integers I mentioned above. I'll edit the question - problem solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to successfully serialize the graph using Boost serialization routines into a string, parse the string and remove the nodes I didn't need and de-serialize the modified string. For 200,000 total nodes in graph and 100,000 that needs to be deleted I was able to successfully finish the operation in less than 2 seconds.

For my particular use-case each vertex has 3 64bit integers. When it needs to be deleted, I mark 2 of those integers as 0s. A valid vertex would never have a 0. When the point comes to clean up the graph - to delete the "deleted" vertices, I follow the above logic.

In the code below removeDeletedNodes() does the string parsing and removing the vertices and mapping the edge numbers.

[image]

Comment: Nice. I'd be interested to know whether `filtered_graph` would be serializable (I suppose it would). In that case it might be faster because of the reduced need for string manipulation.

Answer (score 9):

In your removal branch you re-`tie()` the iterators:

```
boost::tie(vi, vi_end) = boost::vertices(m_graph);
```

This will cause the loop to restart every time you restart the loop. This is *exactly* [Schlemiel The Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm).

I'll find  out whether you can trust `remove_vertex` not triggering a reallocation. If so, it's easily fixed. Otherwise, you'd want an indexer-based loop instead of iterator-based. Or you might be able to work on the raw container (it's a private member, though, as I remember).

**Update** Using `vecS` as the container for vertices is going to cause bad performance here:

> If the `VertexList` template parameter of the `adjacency_list` was `vecS`, then all vertex descriptors, edge descriptors, and iterators for the graph are invalidated by this operation. <...> ***If you need to make frequent use of the `remove_vertex()` function the `listS` selector is a much better choice for the `VertexList` template parameter.***

---

This [small benchmark `test.cpp`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10100393/) compares:

- with `-DSTABLE_IT` (`listS`)

  ```
  $ ./stable 
  Generated 100000 vertices and 5000 edges in 14954ms
  The graph has a cycle? false
  starting selective removal...
  Done in 0ms
  After: 99032 vertices and 4916 edges
  ```
- without `-DSTABLE_IT` (`vecS`)

  ```
  $ ./unstable 
  Generated 100000 vertices and 5000 edges in 76ms
  The graph has a cycle? false
  starting selective removal...
  Done in 396ms
  After: 99032 vertices and 4916 edges
  ```
- using `filtered_graph` (thanks `@cv_and_he` in the comments)

  ```
  Generated 100000 vertices and 5000 edges in 15ms
  The graph has a cycle? false
  starting selective removal...
  Done in 0ms
  After: 99032 vertices and 4916 edges
  Done in 13ms
  ```

You can clearly see that removal is ***much*** faster for `listS` but generating is ***much*** slower.

Comment: The reason had to be done was because when `remove_vertex` was called all iterators were invalidated.

Comment: `vecS` had to be used because I had to detect cyclic dependencies. [boost example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/file_dependency_example.html) This only worked with `vecS`

Comment: @Dula for large graphs adding vertices is gonna be much slower, but my test with a random graph  already confirm that `listS` is ***much*** faster during the removal phase. In general, the algorithms that work "naturally" with `vecS` still work with `listS` iff you prover the `vertex_index_t` propertymap. I'll have a look later

Comment: I think slower generation is OK in my use case. Only the deletes happen in bulk. I'll try and modify the graph to use `listS` and post resulting data.

Comment: @Dula I've added a benchmark confirming the shift in performance characteristics with `vecS` vs. `listS` **updated** with `depth_first_search` to detect cycles (also with `listS`): [**Live On Coliru** (smaller dataset)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a33851249b67e8ef)

Comment: That's awesome...I'm not on the C++11 standard yet. But I'll try to convert them. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need c++11. I'm fixing a glitch where I measured the edge deletion too. Hang on: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce4e4507d964205b)** (fixed answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70438/discussion-between-sehe-and-dula).

Comment: @Dula Here's a c++03 version of the bench/demo code **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e60c3cdccc430b1c)**

Comment: @Dula I remember reading that a good way to "remove" lots of vertices from a graph with a vector vertex_list is creating a filtered_graph that ignores the vertices that are in a set and then simply adding the vertices you want to remove to that set. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0423e864b4573069) is my attemp at implementing it (be sure to check the hasher since I know very little about unordered_sets and it may very well be wrong). The removing part is obviously fast, but I'm not sure how the performance of accessing the filtered_graph after will be (it may be far slower).

Comment: @cv_and_he That's clever! I've added the timings (after making sure that the predicate behaved the same way :)). The only caveats I can think of is that some algorithms will refuse to work on filtered graphs (possibly due to non-mutable properties?) and of course the increased memory requirements. But I think it's a good way to avoid [adapting custom data structures.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/leda_conversion.html)

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see more of the Vtune data.

My experience has been that the default Microsoft allocator can be a big bottleneck when deleting tens of thousands of small objects. Does your Vtune graph show a lot of time in delete or free?

If so, consider switching to a third-party allocator. Nedmalloc is said to be good: http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedmalloc/

<s>Google has one, tcmalloc, which is very well regarded and much faster than the built-in allocators on almost every platform. https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/</s> tcmalloc is not a drop-in for Windows.

Comment: Yes, it does. In the VTune picture 48 seconds are spent in the erase. This would cause the GUID structure to be deleted as well I'm guessing?

Comment: `erase` would cover the destructor as well as the memory free. Can you go deeper?

Comment: I don't think so. That's getting into the C++ containers code isn't it?

Comment: Sure, but that wouldn't normally stop VTune.