# Boost graph list or vec

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph, boost-graph

I've been spending quite a few days working with the boost graph library. As far as I understand, when considering VertexList and EdgeList storage :

vecS :

- possess an index, so can be access with it
- when removing vertices, iterator are invalidated

listS :

- no index
- does not invalidate iterator

It's a bit short but that's to the point for my problem. I need those index number and I want to be able to easily remove vertices later on.

I have a working algorithm with this graph structure :

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, 
        topologicalmap::Intersection_Graph ,
        boost::edge_weight_t, 
        boost::no_property > Graph_boost;
```

I have a custom structure `Intersection_Graph` for my vertices that I need to use. Here I use vecS.

I want to use listS instead to be able to remove vertices. As well, I want to be able to use it later with Dijkstra algorithm.

I kind of understand that I need to have `boost::vertex_index_t` in my list but I am really confused as to how to do it and keep my custom struct at the same time.

I tried something along those lines :

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, 
        boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, topologicalmap::Intersection_Graph>,
        boost::edge_weight_t, 
        boost::no_property > Graph_boost;
```

But I can't even access my custom struct anymore. Plus, index access don't work.

I really need that index access capability since the algorithm my graph will depend on return the index of the parent node. I feel like I could get away with using a Vertex instead of indexes but it would imply a major re-writing of the code and I want to know if I can avoid it.

So my question is : is there any way to have listS behaving in a vecS like manner while keeping the advantages of listS ?

Please, bear with me if it sounds stupid. I'm quite confuse at the moment, so I might have say something stupid. If you need more information, just ask.

Comment: what's wrong with using the vertex_descriptor as intended (that's the stable "index") instead of integral index numbers?

Comment: I use this graph in combination with a previous algorithm that return number of node as integral index number. Using vertex_descriptor means I need to re-write a lot of the previous code since (tell me if I'm wrong) I don't think I can do something like _graph(0) with listS. Plus I will need this for Dikjstra, no ? see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156880/dijkstra-shortest-path-with-vertexlist-lists-in-boost-graph . Or am I mixing everything :S ?

Comment: You do need it for Dijkstra, but as my answer already mentions you can pass it in separately

Comment: Yeah I just saw that. I'll try it soon, thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: Maybe you'll find these answers (and comment threads) interesting: [graph with removable nodes, accessible properties and reliable IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29110540/85371). This sample shows how to pass `vertex_index` separately when required: [Remove 100,000+ nodes from a Boost graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376370/remove-100-000-nodes-from-a-boost-graph/28376521#comment45094293_28376521) (specifically in the comments)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *interior properties* formulation is:

```
property<tag, type, next_property>
```

Of course, unless you make `Intersection_Graph` *behave* like an integral type you cannot use it directly as the *type* of the `vertex_index` property. It's also likely not what you wanted.

This looks closer:

```
boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, topologicalmap::Intersection_Graph>
```

And it would declare *two* properties:

1. an interior property tagged `vertex_index_t` (type `int`)
2. a bundled property (typed `Intersection_Graph`). Note that bundled properties are implicitly accessible through the `vertex_bundle_t` tag.

Now with this in mind, everything should be plain sailing:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddbcb75e715dc867)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>

#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

namespace topologicalmap {
    struct Intersection_Graph {
        std::string bundled;
    };
}

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, 
        boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, topologicalmap::Intersection_Graph>,
        boost::edge_weight_t, 
        boost::no_property > Graph_boost;

int main() {

    std::mt19937 prng { std::random_device {} () };
    Graph_boost g;

    generate_random_graph(g, 10, 20, prng);

    // assign indices
    int i = 0;
    BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, g, Graph_boost) { 
        get(vertex_index, g)[v] = i; 
        g[v].bundled = "id:" + std::to_string(i);

        i++;
    }

    // print the graph using the `bundled` property as a label:
    print_graph(g, get(&topologicalmap::Intersection_Graph::bundled, g));

    // do some index accesses:
    for (int i : {1,7})
        std::cout << "\nVertex at index #" << i << " has a bundled property of '" << g[vertex(i,g)].bundled << "'";
}
```

Which prints e.g. (random generated each run)

```
id:0 <--> id:8 id:8 id:7 id:6 id:1 
id:1 <--> id:3 id:4 id:4 id:3 id:0 id:2 
id:2 <--> id:7 id:1 
id:3 <--> id:1 id:7 id:1 id:9 id:4 
id:4 <--> id:1 id:1 id:5 id:6 id:3 
id:5 <--> id:4 id:9 
id:6 <--> id:0 id:9 id:4 id:8 
id:7 <--> id:3 id:0 id:2 id:9 
id:8 <--> id:0 id:0 id:6 
id:9 <--> id:7 id:6 id:3 id:5 

Vertex at index #1 has a bundled property of 'id:1'
Vertex at index #7 has a bundled property of 'id:7'
```

Notes:

- the fact that the graph "knows" `vertex_index` now doesn't mean it gets maintained; you have to fill it yourself:

  ```
  int i = 0;
  BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, g, Graph_boost) get(vertex_index, g)[v] = i++;
  ```
- you don't actually need to have `vertex_index` associated with your graph type, because you can pass it in as a named parameter to all relevant algorithms AFAIK. This includes constructing derived property maps that rely on a vertex_index (e.g. [`make_iterator_property_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/property_map/doc/iterator_property_map.html))
- I believe it's also possible to associate a vertex index using graph traits (but I haven't done so in the past). This seems like a nice way to go if you e.g. wanted to store the index in a member of your `Intersection_Graph` struct.
- Like I said in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243908/boost-graph-list-or-vec/30248156#comment48596458_30243908) you could probably not require any of this if you stored `vertex_descriptor`s instead of integral indexes.

Comment: slightly modernized code sample http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37994618e96e7b42