# How to view vertices/edges from boost graph list containers

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I'm trying to use `listS` as the vertex/edge container so that I can remove edges safely. However, I'm running into a problem - I don't know how to see my vertices or edges! When I try to iterate through them and print them out, it only prints out their address for some reason.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_iterator.hpp>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef boost::graph_traits <Graph>::edge_iterator edgeIt;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator vertexIt;
typedef map<vertex_t,size_t> IndexMap;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Graph g;

    IndexMap mapIndex;

    vertex_t v0 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t v1 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t v2 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    vertex_t v3 = boost::add_vertex(g);
    mapIndex[v0] = 0;
    mapIndex[v1] = 1;
    mapIndex[v2] = 2;
    mapIndex[v3] = 3;
    boost::add_edge(v0,v2,g);
    boost::add_edge(v1,v3,g);
    boost::add_edge(v1,v0,g);


    for(pair<vertexIt,vertexIt> vi = boost::vertices(g); vi.first != vi.second; ++vi.first) {
        cout << *vi.first << endl;
    }

    for(pair<edgeIt,edgeIt> ei = boost::edges(g); ei.first != ei.second; ++ei.first) {
        cout << source(*ei.first, g) << " -> " << target(*ei.first, g) << endl;
        cout << *ei.first << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
0x7f9409404b10
0x7f9409404b70
0x7f9409404c00
0x7f9409404c40
0x7f9409404b10 -> 0x7f9409404c00
(0x7f9409404b10,0x7f9409404c00)
0x7f9409404b70 -> 0x7f9409404c40
(0x7f9409404b70,0x7f9409404c40)
0x7f9409404b70 -> 0x7f9409404b10
(0x7f9409404b70,0x7f9409404b10)
```

If I use `vecS` instead of `listS`, it works fine, but then I run into trouble when removing vertices. So how can I view edges/vertices with `listS`?

**EDIT: SOLUTIONS**

SOLUTION 1:

Use a struct to store a property:

```
struct vertex {
    int id;
}

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, vertex> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef boost::graph_traits <Graph>::edge_iterator edgeIt;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator vertexIt;
typedef map<vertex_t,size_t> IndexMap;

//MAKE YOUR GRAPH
...
//

//Assign vertex IDs
int currentID = 0;
for(pair<vertexIt,vertexIt> it = boost::vertices(g); it.first != it.second; ++it.first) {
    g[*it.first].id = currentID++;
}

//Access them when displaying edges:
for(pair<vertexIt,vertexIt> it = boost::vertices(g); it.first != it.second; ++it.first) {
    cout << g[*it.first].id << endl;
}

//Access them when displaying vertices:
for(pair<edgeIt,edgeIt> it = boost::edges(g); it.first != it.second; ++it.first) {
    cout << g[source(*it.first,g)].id << " " << g[target(*it.first,g)].id << endl;
}
```

SOLUTION 2:

Use property maps (continuing on from my first code)

```
for(pair<vertexIt,vertexIt> vi = boost::vertices(g); vi.first != vi.second; ++vi.first) {
    cout << mapIndex[*vi.first] << endl;
}

for(IndexMap::iterator it = mapIndex.begin(); it != mapIndex.end(); ++it) {
    cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The vertex and edge data types in Boost are abstracted as [`descriptors`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/Graph.html). They are more or less pointers.

When using `vecS`, the descriptors are `size_t` indexes and their corresponding vertex and edge index map is available by default. If you want an integer index for your edges and vertices with `listS` you have to create it yourself.

I think a good method of doing this in a Boost-like way is this.

```
typedef std::map<vertex_descriptor,size_t> StdVertexIndexMap;
StdVertexIndexMap viMap;
typedef boost::associative_property_map<StdVertexIndexMap> VertexIndexMap;
VertexIndexMap v_index(viMap);
vertex_iterator vi,ve;
size_t i = 0;
for(boost::tie(vi,ve) = boost::vertices(g); vi != ve; ++vi){
    boost::put(v_index,*vi,i);
    ++i;
}
```

Similarly for Edges. See my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263594/adding-a-vertex-index-to-lists-graph-on-the-fly-for-betweenness-centrality) for context. Wrapping it in a `boost::associative_property_map` or something similar is the Boost way so that the algorithms that use `boost::get` and `boost::put` will work correctly.

If you don't plan on using it in a boost algorithm you could just use a simple `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

(Speculation) One possibility is that you are returning value of a pointer, i.e. address.

Try and use the dereference operator twice `**` to test what is on these addresses and see if the returned values is reasonable.

Comment: Hmm I get these errors like this if I do that:

    test.cpp:35:17: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('reference' (aka 'unsigned long') invalid)
        cout << **vi.first << endl;
                ^~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @user2520385 OK, try access operator after the the element, i.e. something like: `*vi.first.` or `*vi.first->`.

Comment: Ok so I think I know the problem now. When storing vertices/edges in a List container, they simply don't have an 'index'. You need to either assign an index map or use a struct workaround. 
I will edit my main post.

Comment: @user2520385 you can formulate it as an answer and then accept it, it's a valid action