# Removing multiple vertices from a boost::adjacency_list graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I'm using boost graph_traits and defined a graph like this:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list <boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, NodeInfo, EdgeInfo> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
```

Each of my vertices has coordinates attatched and I intend to find duplicate vertices (vertices in the same location). So I build a list that contains these "clusters":

```
std::vector<std::vector<Vertex>> clusters;
```

Now I tried to merge each cluster in one single vertex (list of vertices). To do this I call for each vertex of a cluster `clusters[i]`:

```
boost::clear_vertex(v, graph)
boost::remove_vertex(v, graph);
```

However I noticed that still duplicates remain. I guess that it's related to a changes in indices while deleting as I use `vecS` for the vertex-list.

What is the reason for this and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `vectorS` the descriptors are just as unstable as iterators: they get invalidated on insert/remove. See [Iterator and Descriptor Stability/Invalidation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html)

Of course the solution described there (using `listS`) might not apply to your situation.

In that case, rethink your problem, and consider filtering the graph (without actually removing vertices) or mark vertices as deleted. See here for inspiration:

- [Remove 100,000+ nodes from a Boost graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376370/remove-100-000-nodes-from-a-boost-graph/28376521#28376521) (also the comment by _jv)

Comment: Is it possible to sort the list of vertices to remove in descending order and remove them this way safely (as the removal of an index i only should affect the indices > i  in an std::vector)?

Comment: In principle, yes. However, I'd stick to the documented stability/invalidation guarantees. And "remove_vertex(), which when used with an adjacency_list where VertexList=vecS, invalidates all iterators and descriptors for the graph" does **not** give you that lee-way.

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work as I expected. Maybe my assumptions on how it works internally were wrong. Now I tried to use a filtered_graph but have trouble converting it back to an adjacency_list.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/graph/doc/copy_graph.html should be a good help